# What does an empty select do?

Tags: go

I found the following code in `net/http/httptest` and wonder what the empty `select` statement does in Go.

```
go s.Config.Serve(s.Listener)
if *serve != "" {
  fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "httptest: serving on", s.URL)
  select {}
}
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

An empty `select{}` statement *blocks* forever. It is similar to an empty `for{}` statement.

On most (all?) supported Go architectures, the empty select will yield CPU. An empty for-loop won't, i.e. it will "spin" on 100% CPU.

Comment: That was my guess. However I still find it semantically awkward, because `select` suggests a condition and not a loop.

Comment: AFAIK an empty for would be intensive on the cpu (at least that's how empty infinite loops work in other languages). While in OP's example it's likely that select{} is used to prevent the main goroutine from exiting.

Comment: In CSP-speak, the empty select is like `STOP`, a process that never proceeds. This is akin to a self-deadlock and I imagine it doesn't get used all that often. However, the question proposed an interesting and genuine use-case for this pattern. An empty `for{}` loop is a self-livelock, different because it consumes cpu resources.

Comment: It appears that it's idiomatic Go to use `select{}` to _block_ the main goroutine which yields the CPU. Since the main goroutine hasn't returned, this leaves the process around and one can analyze the behavior of the other goroutines.

Answer (score 24):

On Mac OS X, in Go,  `for { }` will cause the CPU% to max, and the process's STATE will be `running`

`select { }`, on the other hand, will not cause the CPU% to max, and the process's STATE will be `sleeping`

Answer (score 10):

The empty `select` statement just blocks the current goroutine.

As for why you'd do this, here is one reason. This snippet is equivalent

```
if *serve != "" {
  fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "httptest: serving on", s.URL)
  s.Config.Serve(s.Listener)
} else {
  go s.Config.Serve(s.Listener)
}
```

It's better in that there isn't a wasted goroutine. It's worse in that now there is code repetition. The author optimized for less code repetition over a wasted resource. Note however the permanently block goroutine is trivial to detect and may have zero cost over the duplicating version.