# What's difference between select{} and for{} in golang?

Tags: go

I find a similar question: [What does an empty select do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18661602/what-does-an-empty-select-do)

`for{}` will cover 100% cpu usage.

`select{}` ask the channel case can read or write or not. But no case in the select. `select{}` will use 0% cpu usage? Or just like the `for{}`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`for{}` uses 100% CPU because it continuously executes the loop iteration.

`select{}` uses nearly 0% CPU because it causes the goroutine to block, which means the scheduler puts it to sleep, and it will never be woken.