# golang dbus server example

Tags: go, server, dbus

Golang [dbus module](https://github.com/godbus/dbus) has provided the following [example](https://github.com/godbus/dbus/blob/master/_examples/server.go) but it is not clear how the server receives a message and respond. A ping/pong example is appreciated:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/godbus/dbus"
    "github.com/godbus/dbus/introspect"
)

const intro = `
<node>
    <interface name="com.github.guelfey.Demo">
        <method name="Foo">
            <arg direction="out" type="s"/>
        </method>
    </interface>` + introspect.IntrospectDataString + `</node> `

type foo string

func (f foo) Foo() (string, *dbus.Error) {
    fmt.Println(f)
    return string(f), nil
}

func main() {
    conn, err := dbus.ConnectSessionBus()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    f := foo("Bar!")
    conn.Export(f, "/com/github/guelfey/Demo", "com.github.guelfey.Demo")
    conn.Export(introspect.Introspectable(intro), "/com/github/guelfey/Demo",
        "org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable")

    reply, err := conn.RequestName("com.github.guelfey.Demo",
        dbus.NameFlagDoNotQueue)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if reply != dbus.RequestNameReplyPrimaryOwner {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "name already taken")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Println("Listening on com.github.guelfey.Demo / /com/github/guelfey/Demo ...")
    select {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is just my impression from reading the program and the docs.  Test for yourself to see if this is accurate)

https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/godbus/dbus#Conn.Export

```golang
func (conn *Conn) Export(v interface{}, path ObjectPath, iface string) error
```

> If a method call on the given path and interface is received, an exported method with the same name is called with v as the receiver if the parameters match and the last return value is of type *Error. If this *Error is not nil, it is sent back to the caller as an error. Otherwise, a method reply is sent with the other return values as its body.

The program passes `f` of type `foo` to `conn.Export`.

`foo` has this method which matches the pattern described:

```golang
func (f foo) Foo() (string, *dbus.Error)
```

The response is the return values from this function not including the final error, i.e, `string(f)`. (`"Bar!"` in this case).

The empty select statement `select {}` at the end is a clever trick that I have never seen before.  It is simply a statement that block forever.  You can read more about it in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18661602/what-does-an-empty-select-do).  It's being used here simply to stop the `main` goroutine from terminating.  In Go, the entire process will immediately end when the main goroutine finishes.

Given that this empty select is a "clever trick", it's probably better form to accompany it with a simple comment explaining:

```golang
// Blocks forever
select {}
```

---

Probably the reason why this example is confusing is because this `Export` method is quite magical.  It takes a vaguely named  empty interface value and figures out what to do with it based on some internal process that likely uses reflection.  Unless you read the documentation for the function it's hard to guess what it'll do.

Comment: Thanks, that method is called. Still doesn't understand the empty `select {}` at the end of code. I was looking for come channel to listen on.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm a go beginner but somehow doesn't fell good about the design decisions of this project and it is the only one on the market. Cannot upvote more but come back soon with another question.